# Java - How can a dialog be displayed at the same location it was closed?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, escaping, location

I have a dialog class that extends EscapeDialog in Java. How can I get the location on the screen that is was closed, and have it show at that same location when the user opens the dialog again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for the windowClosing event and save the dialog location somewhere: in memory, on disk,...

```
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
          // save the dialog.getLocation()
        }
    });
```

Then, the next time you open the dialog, read the location from the place you saved it to and call the `dialog.setLocation()` before you display it.